# How to change the image quality in CameraPictureBackground plugin in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I used [CameraPictureBackground](https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-camerapicturebackground) plugin:
It successfully captured the image and saved but the quality of the image was too bad. Is there any option to capture the image with same quality as we capture with camera app.

```
function success(imgurl) {
  console.log("Imgurl = " + imgurl);
  //here I added my function to upload the saved pictures
  //on my internet server using file-tranfer plugin
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}

function CaptureBCK() {
    var options = {
    name: "Image", //image suffix
    dirName: "CameraPictureBackground", //foldername
    orientation: "portrait", //or landscape
    type: "back" //or front
    };

    window.plugins.CameraPictureBackground.takePicture(success, onFail, options);
}


    <button onclick="CaptureBCK();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Cordova-plugin-camera plugin to capture images. It has various options to save the image on a range of 0-100 quality basis. 100 being high quality.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera